# Script Task C# Try-Catch exception message into SQL Table

Tags: c#, sql, ssis, msbi

I have a Script task inside a foreach loop in SSIS package, the script task create a folder and copy a file. My `Directory.CreateDirectory` and `File.Copy` is inside a Try and the exception is inside the Catch.

My package should copy all the files and then update some columns in a table with the current date, filepath, status and error message. If the file can't be finded, the package should continue running and update the table with the exception message. The following code shows the catch exception, my SSIS variable `ErrorDescription` should update the column `ErrorDescription` in the table, but if the file can't be finded the entire row is not updated, just update the next row when a file is copied. My main goal is to find a solution to update the ErrorDescription colum with the exception message. Can anyone help or suggest some ideas for me please?

```
Dts.Variables["User::ErrorDescription"].Value = "";
try
            {
               //Code here works fine

                Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
            }

            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Dts.Variables["User::ErrorDescription"].Value = e.Message.ToString();
                MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
                Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Failure;

            }
```

My SQL Query is something like this:

```
"Update [Records]
Set [CurrentDate] = '"+(DT_WSTR, 250) @[User::CurrentDate]+"',
[FilePath] =  '"+@[User::FilePath]+"',
[Status] = '"+@[User::Status]+"',
[ErrorDescription] = '"+ @[User::ErrorDescription]+"'
Where [ID] = '"+(DT_WSTR, 25)@[User::ID]+"';"
```

Comment: Sooooo you SQL Query which you've built via string concatenation of SSIS variables - is that expression attached to a variable or did you do it directly in the Execute SQL Task. Is there a reason you went with string concatenation instead of parameterization?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. My SQL query is attached to a variable in an Execute SQL task. I had trouble with parameters using ADO.net so I went with a query attached to a variable.